# Onion site illegal in my country. Can only visiting get me caught?

Tags: security

People hello,

When I visit onion website that are illegal inside my country can I get caught if I have highest security setting no java no script and only browse the website? No opening anything?

How likely I be caught when Im not stupid and use tails?

Onion site is not illegal in many other country but my. ISP probably saving IP for 1-3 months.

Can I browse good spirit or is there a risk of getting in trouble?

Comment: Is there anybody: Help me please? Clearify the onion service I want to use is not illegal in other country but in many islamic country. How big is the risk if I do only use high security settings, no java and only tails. Do other onion services, no links clicking, no downloads. Only read and write to .onion website? Can my government catch me?

Comment: Welcome! Please refrain from providing additional details/questions/comments in an answer as they belong in the question/comments section. I think you should give it a day or so for the question to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get in trouble just by using tor, don't do it. ISP's can only see that you are using tor and nothing else, however ISP's can perform an [end-to-end confirmation attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147402/how-do-traffic-correlation-attacks-against-tor-users-work) on you if they can find patterns in both ends of the communication channel (you and the site). Meaning that if they have access to the server you are trying to connect, you can get caught pretty easily.